External Client Apps (using JWT) in Managed Packages Default to "Admin Approved Users Are Pre-Authorized" OAuth Policy
I am building a Managed Package that includes an External Client App using the JWT Bearer Token Flow for authentication. I need to ensure that the OAuth Policy of the Connected App is set to "Admin approved users are pre-authorized" automatically upon installation of the package.
Here is my key question:
Is it possible to include this setting directly within the package, or programmatically enable it during the post-installation process?
Any insights or best practices for handling this scenario in Managed Package development would be greatly appreciated! Thank you in advance!

Yes. If we set the OAuth plugin policy to Admin approved users are pre-authorized in source i.e. DevHub org , same policy is reflected in the subscriber org.
Above scenario is mentioned in this link. Extracting it below from the link:

Packaged apps with an OAuth plugin can be deployed with their own
unique OAuth settings or they can reference the settings of the org
where the app was developed.

Comparison with connected apps can be found here.
Reference - Dreamforce 2024 demo.

Based on my understanding, it seems that External Client Apps' Package Defaults settings alone cannot achieve the default configuration of "Admin approved users are pre-authorized" in the subscriber org.
And also I attempted to include ExtlClntAppOauthConfigurablePolicies metadata in the package, but it seems this metadata cannot be packaged. (It is automatically generated in the subscriber org upon installation.)
After the installation, the settings in the subscriber org do not reflect the configuration("Admin approved users are pre-authorized") from the source org (DevHub).

In that case, above article is conveying incorrect info.
